# Use glm to predict on fresh data

Tags: r, model, glm

I'm relatively new to glm - so please bear with me.

I have created a glm  (logistic regression) to predict whether an individual CONTINUES studies ("0") or does NOTCONTINUE ("1").  I am interested in predicting the latter.  The glm uses seven factors in the dataset and the confusion matrices are very good for what I need and combining seven years' of data have also been done.  Straight-forward.

However, I now need to apply the model to the current years' data, which of course does not have the NOTCONTINUE column in it.  Lets say the glm model is "CombinedYears" and the new data is "Data2020"

How can I use the glm model to get predictions of who will ("0") or will NOT ("1") continue their studies?  Do I need to insert a NOTCONTINUE column into the latest file ?? I have tried this structure

Predict2020 <- predict(CombinedYears, data.frame(Data2020), type = 'response')

but the output only holds values <0.5.

Any help very gratefully appreciated.  Thank you in advance

Comment: You are using `predict` correctly. The results you see are the probability that each given individual will not continue. If your drop-out rate is, say, 10% overall this is entirely possible. Suppose you had a model that correctly predicted the probability of throwing a six when you roll a dice as being 0.167. So if you threw 100 dice you would expect to get 16 or 17 sixes. However, you can't expect the model to predict _which_ dice will be a six. It will tell you the probability for each throw. Your model can only tell you the probability that an individual will not continue.

Comment: Thank you.   Did not fully appreciate that, but I do now !   New to this level of statistics and learning as I go !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you already created a prediction model to predict whether a particular student will continue studies or not. You used the glm package and your model name is CombinedYears.

Now, what you have to know is that your problem is a binary classification and you used logistic regression for this. The output of your model when you apply it on new data, or even the same data used to fit the model, is probabilities. These are values between zero and one. In the development phase of your model, you need to determine the cutoff threshold of these probabilities which you can use later on when you predict new data. For example, you may determine 0.5 as a cutoff, and every probability above that is considered NOTCONTINUE and below that is CONTINUE. However, the best threshold can be determined from your data as well by maximizing both specificity and sensitivity. This can be done by calculating the area under the receiver operating characteristic curve (AUC). There are many packages than can do this for you, such as pROC and AUC packages in R. The same packages can determine the best cutoff as well.

What you have to do is the following:

1. Determine the cutoff threshold after calculating the AUC

   ```
   library(pROC)
   roc_object = roc(your_fit_data$NOTCONTINUE ~ fitted(CombinedYears))
   coords(roc.roc_object, "best", ret="threshold", transpose = FALSE)
   ```
2. Use your model to predict on your new data year (as you did)

   ```
    Predict2020 = predict(CombinedYears, data.frame(Data2020), type = 'response')
   ```
3. Now, the content of Predict2020 is just probabilities for each
   student. Use the cutoff you obtained from step (1) to classify your
   students accordingly

Comment: THANK YOU !!!   Gave me just the guidance I needed -  have a great weekend.

Comment: Sorry !  I though I had this working this morning and did get a threshold from the coords line and managed to partition my data.  However, returning this afternoon to develop the script further and the roc_object line now generates an error.   Here's what I have roc_object <- roc(Data2010_17$NOTCONTINUE ~ fitted(Data2010_17Model)) where the first term is the combined data-set NOTCONTINUE indicator/factor.   Inside "fitted" is the output from the glm function for the combined dataset.  Struggling with this now.....sorry.

Comment: This structure has resolved the error message  -  roc_object <- roc(Data2010_17$NOTCONTINUE, Data2010_17Model$fitted.values).    Thanks for your help and guidance.  I am learning - slowly at times !